# Push Notification to Android using FCM (c#)

Tags: android, c#-4.0, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to send a Push Notification to Android Using FCM and implementation in C#.

I have used the following code and it give me the id in Response which seems all ok.

But i didnt received any notification in my device as the device id is correct and received notification if i send it through the FCM Console.

Any Suggestion would help.

Thanks

```
 var value = "This is first message to Android";
            WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", "AAAAosN-NoU:APA91bHg6Iv8qj2giVvSRVVFze4L6Si0VTwctkNaRRqlI7qffKAMPHo4fd52SgZcB8Ring-mnPrkqjodTGrSru_bXKRQD9n4eVxhs8pTbkXac1gotCM77EixMUXTplXhceIm1o20BVXvkHO1HQZBti990ijebUW1fg"));
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", "699064530565"));

            string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + "APA91bFD6jRdsSzQ37_rB2x4C8wJzcDzgdjZuhf4hFgzCndeESCEnHrW3sRQcwetljExhlEUrpquhdTW2C24qjtb-PJuUUhpnev3Zn_DDH6aF7PStFRPYvWSQcfLFd14sueLmbhCvcqr" + "";

            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

                using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                        {
                            string sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Nobody knows....leave it i will resolve myself

Comment: Please look into your PostData and share exact error after debug.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into your PostData. Here is example how your data should be formatted.

```
 var PostData= new

            {
                data = {your custom data you want to send},
                to = deviceId,

                notification = new

                {

                    body = "Got notify",

                    title = Alert,

                },
                priority ="normal"
            };

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            var json = serializer.Serialize(PostData);

            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
```

And can you please share exact error by debugging your code . Well hopefully above code resolve you problem.